# Route the traffic to different instances based on IP addresses in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes

I want to route the traffic from the specific country to the specific server by using AWS service(route53 or ELB something like that). For example,  routes all the traffic from Singapore to webserver1. Route all the traffic from Japanese to another webserver2. Can I do it by using AWS service. If I can, how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into Route53 Geo routing?

Comment: Hi @kenlukas , I solve the problem by using route53 geo routing. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Route 53 for that purpose. Route 53 has a [geolocation routing policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo). Here are [the steps to setup that](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/geolocation-routing-policy/).

Comment: Hi Victor, thanks for your answer. I solve the problem by using the geolocation routing policy! Thanks!